# Error 3120006: No available wallet Ensure that you have created a wallet and have it open

Tags: cleos, wallet

I'm create wallet EOS follow document

```
cleos create account inita tester EOS4toFS3YXEQCkuuw1aqDLrtHim86Gz9u3hBdcBw5KNPZcursVHq EOS7d9A3uLe6As66jzN8j44TXJUqJSK3bFjjEEqR4oTvNAB3iM9SA
```

Reponse

```
Error 3120006: No available wallet
Ensure that you have created a wallet and have it open
```

Before I using Docker create network and create Alias for cleos

```
docker network inspect eosdev
```

Return

```
[
{
    "Name": "eosdev",
    "Id": "8a3810e2b6f0c49bbfad5cad2e1564b9c6b8fd7a2c87594c77a4cc3e52362575",
    "Created": "2018-11-14T12:38:16.079678634Z",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": {},
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": false,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {
        "cadf022427a50f92b8971f4e388d31c764df090bc7fbf1a83de77537d98b4a60": {
            "Name": "keosd",
            "EndpointID": "6bbb099480923338d6749068f875e7e81523b4282e84c7e3822cd2568897c5a6",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
            "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "f94432b4985382f8ee103b3f4fa08f0e4b044c2eaf422e088d2c7ce971de2a30": {
            "Name": "nodeos",
            "EndpointID": "7b31dcf1d8c1813585155c805977ac9264370e237691a9c129b6651fcd824726",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
            "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
    "Options": {},
    "Labels": {}
}
```

]

And next

```
alias cleos='docker exec -it nodeos /opt/eosio/bin/cleos --url http://127.0.0.1:8888 --wallet-url http://172.18.0.3:9876'
```

Maybe I did something wrong, help me.

Comment: did you create a wallet? `cleos wallet create`

Comment: Yep, I had create wallet follow this post
 https://medium.com/@nalamsubash/step-by-step-guide-for-cleos-wallet-c58c0ebbc4cd

Comment: But follow Document ```cleos create account [OPTIONS] creator name OwnerKey ActiveKey ``` How to create OwnerKey and ActiveKey. If use  ```cleos create key --to-console ``` return public_key and private_key.

Comment: `ownerkey` and `activekey` are the public keys corresponding to the secret keys managing those permissions

Comment: How to get owerkey and activekey?

Comment: I had public key and private key with ```cleos create key --to-console``` I need OwnerKey and ActiveKey For create account. ``` https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/v1.3.0/reference#cleos-create-account ```

Comment: I solved this problem here
[https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/3168/error-requirederror-ownerkey-create-a-new-account-on-the-blockchain-assumes-s](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/3168/error-requirederror-ownerkey-create-a-new-account-on-the-blockchain-assumes-s)
Thank all for support.