# ERROR: RequiredError: OwnerKey Create a new account on the blockchain (assumes system contract does not restrict RAM usage)

Tags: cleos, accounts, wallet, owner-key

I have wallet create with cleos

```
cleos wallet list
```

Return

```
Wallets:
[
  "demowalleteos"
]
```

I create pair key with cleos

```
cleos create key --to-console
```

But, when I create account system require owner_key. How to get owner_key and active_key?

```
cleos create account demoaccounteos EOS58wkLHPuYfX8jpvEYZi6PviCkk7v4bBQSU2sa8WJvJtXWa7XBX
```

return

```
ERROR: RequiredError: OwnerKey
Create a new account on the blockchain (assumes system contract does not restrict RAM usage)
Usage: /opt/eosio/bin/cleos create account [OPTIONS] creator name OwnerKey [ActiveKey]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not because of the "wallet eosio", but you didn't specify the creator in

> cleos create account demoaccounteos EOS58wkLHPuYfX8jpvEYZi6PviCkk7v4bBQSU2sa8WJvJtXWa7XBX

**The create account usage is :**

```
cleos create account [OPTIONS] creator name OwnerKey [ActiveKey]
```

It's just lucky **eosio** is a system predefined account,and you can run this without a "wallet eosio"

> cleos create account eosio demoaccounteos EOS58wkLHPuYfX8jpvEYZi6PviCkk7v4bBQSU2sa8WJvJtXWa7XBX

otherwise if you create a "wallet neosio", you still  get error when run

> cleos create account neosio demowalletxx EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV EOS5VCBkdvu2BrPSiPGD3K2batKjgs3F51iETMXNn8bqZqQGqg1WJ

Answer (score 0):

I had add wallet eosio

```
eosio
Public key: EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV
Private key: 5KQwrPbwdL6PhXujxW37FSSQZ1JiwsST4cqQzDeyXtP79zkvFD3
```

This public just for testing

```
cleos wallet create -n eosio --to-console

cleos wallet import --private-key 5KQwrPbwdL6PhXujxW37FSSQZ1JiwsST4cqQzDeyXtP79zkvFD3 -n eosio

cleos create account eosio demowalletxx EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV EOS5VCBkdvu2BrPSiPGD3K2batKjgs3F51iETMXNn8bqZqQGqg1WJ
```

Return

```
executed transaction: 3cd2bc760c56d67f1f96c65c6ee4441b32747127d72aa9762f7cca1e40b59430  200 bytes  16343 us
#         eosio <= eosio::newaccount            {"creator":"eosio","name":"demowalletxx","owner":{"threshold":1,"keys":[{"key":"EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYc...
warning: transaction executed locally, but may not be confirmed by the network yet
```

OK Now check info account

```
cleos get account demowalletxx
```

Return

```
created: 2018-11-16T06:06:04.000
permissions: 
     owner     1:    1 EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV
        active     1:    1 EOS5VCBkdvu2BrPSiPGD3K2batKjgs3F51iETMXNn8bqZqQGqg1WJ
memory: 
     quota:       unlimited  used:      2.66 KiB  

net bandwidth: 
     used:               unlimited
     available:          unlimited
     limit:              unlimited

cpu bandwidth:
     used:               unlimited
     available:          unlimited
     limit:              unlimited
```

Thank all for support.